# trying to intent a float array android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

I am trying to intent a float array in android but for some reason I can't seem to understand why it won't work? The array comes across as null here is my code:

```
Toast.makeText(Results.this, "Float array:" + dataVals2  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent resultintent = new Intent(Results.this, linechartresults.class);
resultintent.putExtra("results",dataVals2);

startActivity(resultintent);
```

Have added in a Toast message to ensure the array does have values before trying to intent, each time it does.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
float [] dataVals2 = i.getFloatArrayExtra("results");

Toast.makeText(linechartresults.this, "New Array" + dataVals2  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

dataVals.add(new Entry(0,dataVals2[0]));
dataVals.add(new Entry(1,dataVals2[1]));
dataVals.add(new Entry(2,dataVals2[2]));
dataVals.add(new Entry(3,dataVals2[3]));
```

Again added in a Toast message to see if the array has value each time it says null

Comment: maybe the context you are passing is not working try getBaseContext() as the first argument in when initializing resultintent

Comment: I have tried this too unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: then please try to show some more code to understand your problem better

Comment: I have found a work around for my issue so will be closing it now